# Pod spec lint not updating

Tags: terminal, cocoapods, podspec

I got the following error after running `pod spec lint`:

```
Calebs-MacBook-Pro:JacquardToolkit calebrudnicki$ pod spec lint

 -> JacquardToolkit (1.1.4)
     - ERROR | [iOS] xcodebuild: Returned an unsuccessful exit code. You can use `--verbose` for more information.
- NOTE  | xcodebuild:  note: Using new build system
- NOTE  | [iOS] xcodebuild:  note: Planning build
- NOTE  | [iOS] xcodebuild:  note: Constructing build description
- ERROR | [iOS] xcodebuild:  
JacquardToolkit/JacquardToolkit/JSQRCodeScannerView.swift:47:40: error: type 'String' has no member 'center'

Analyzed 1 podspec.

[!] The spec did not pass validation, due to 2 errors.
```

After going back into the project and updating the line in question, and running `pod spec lint` again, I still get the same error even when that line of code isn't there. How do I get this to pass with the most updated code?

Comment: first run `pod lib lint` command and update your local code. if it is working fine than run `pod spec lint` command.

Comment: `pod lib lint` passes but `pod spec lint` still doesn't

Comment: can you post new upcoming error after executing `pod spec lint` ?

Answer (score 0):

Issue resolved. All I needed to do was update my tag and it all worked. Here were my steps:

1. `git tag 1.1.5` (I was on 1.1.4 before)
2. `git push origin --tags`
3. `pod lib lint`
4. `pod spec lint`
5. `pod trunk push`

Now my pod is updated.